# How often do Tor exit nodes change Ip addresses?

Tags: relays, exit-relays, censorship, exit-policies

A majority of Tor traffic is routed through around ~80 exit nodes

I was wondering how often do these exit nodes change their ip addresses?

There is a list of exit nodes here

https://torstatus.blutmagie.de/

Does the "Uptime" column signify since how long the ip address has remained the same?

Or if not, does anyone have a rough idea on how big the time interval is?

Answer (score 2):

Typically the IP address won't change. A large number of exit nodes are on dedicated servers or VPSs, so the public IP will likely stay same unless the owner moves to a new server. In this case they'll usually carry over the same `secret_id_key` so history and flags stay the same in Atlas/Globe even with the new IP.

Uptime only measures how long the node (server) has been running Tor. If the server or the Tor service is restarted on the server then that date will refresh.